# In jQuery AJAX, why $(selector).post() and $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On w3school, I found that the definition of AJAX `post` and `get` are different.

Post:

```
$(selector).post(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

Get

```
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

Why `post` method with *selector* and `get` method hasn't ?

Comment: Please provide the link to the w3schools page you're referring to.

Comment: actually, the w3schools page found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp states that it's perfectly valid to use $.post(...), too. I think it's just a typo, there's no selector needed. *edit:* as of this site: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp they use the right syntax for post, too.

Comment: `.post` is defined at `jQuery` object. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post

Comment: I think about jQuery reference, you should consult its official site [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), where the sintax definition is the right one `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

Comment: It may be a typo, I found `.post`'s definition on jQuery official website. Thankx to all of your. W3school definition, see [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp); jQuery API, see [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an answer out of my comment, for others landing here:

Actually, the w3schools page found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) (and I think that's the page you refer to)  states in its examples that it's perfectly valid to use `$.post(...)`. I think it's just a typo, there's no selector needed.

on this w3schools site [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) they use the right syntax for post, too.

Please remember, just because it's a largely known site like stackoverflow or w3schools, there's no need that they're right every time. Even worse, it's almost every time better to check it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice. :)